# python cannot find module(opencv) even though it is installed

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install OpenCV on my raspberry pi 3(I'm using this tutorial https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/) after installation finished, I check it using the c++ library the module OpenCV has been installed

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pkg-config --modversion opencv4
4.5.5
```

and when I use the python library the result is

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

and then I check-in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages $ ls
cv2
```

Comment: Have you installed openCV for C++ or Python?

Comment: yes, I've installed it

Comment: My question was which one? Python or C++?

Comment: Did you install using Method 1 or 2? From site packages or by compiling yourself?